# Can rsync copy directories over links

Tags: rsync, symlink

I have the following scenario where I need to copy directories which sometimes can be links and sometimes a directory with the same name. For instance, suppose this is the initial setup:

Source:
/workspace/test/source/dir1 -> /tmp/test1

Destination:
/workspace/test/dest/dir1 -> /tmp/test1

Now, suppose I remove the link in the source and create a folder with the same name, so now it looks like this:

Source:
/workspace/test/source/dir1

Destination:
/workspace/test/dest/dir1 -> /tmp/test1

What I'd like to do now, is to use rsync to copy the **actual folder** and "overwrite" the link, so it would look like:

Source:
/workspace/test/source/dir1

Destination:
/workspace/test/dest/dir1

Is there any way to do it via rsync? I know that if I use the rsync one level above, ie /workspace/test/source, it will work. Unfortunetly, I have to use the lowest level rsync.

Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour of `rsync`.

Example

```
## Preamble
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir src dst stuff
$ touch stuff/{a,b,c}
$ ( cd src && ln -s /tmp/stuff dir1 )
$ ( cd dst && ln -s /tmp/stuff dir1 )

## Symlinks are retained
$ cd /tmp
$ rsync -avv src/ dst/

## Change scenario
$ ls -l src
$ rm src/dir1 && cp -a /tmp/stuff src/dir1

## Symlinks are replaced according to the source
$ cd /tmp
$ rsync -avv src/ dst/
$ ls -l dst
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
My intention is to rsync src/dir1 dst/dir1. I know that in top level it works, but the problem is I have to use the lowest level directory.

Comment: @Emil it can't work below the symlink because that's not part of the copy process